# PHP cURL SSL CERT

Tags: php, ssl, curl, key

I have a situation while trying to do a GET method with curl to get xml from distant web api.

```
    $url = 'xxxx.com'
    $key = '/KEY/PRIVATE.KEY'
    $perm = '/KEY/CERT.PEM'
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSLCERT         => $perm ,
        CURLOPT_SSLKEY          => $key,
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
    );
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl , $options);
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

I have to link SSL cert and pem, but $resp is always returned as false.

This is what my cURL request should be in command prompt :

```
curl -k  -v -X GET "[-URL-]" --cert ./KEY/CERT.pem --key ./KEY/PRIVATE.KEY
```

Any help would be strongly appreciated...

**EDIT**

So, I used two methods to try to debug :

With `stderr` I have:

```
string ''.' unknown as intern or extern command, program file or executable file

' (length=117)
```

And with `die(curl_error($curl))` I get this :

```
unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)
```

So, I actually make my URL with two string (`$url = a . b`), but this is supposed to work, or am I crazy?

For the ssl error, I don't get why I have this issue since this works totally fine on command prompt...

**EDIT 2**

So, I found out how to solve in part my issue : I had to use `realpath()`.

But now I have a new issue :

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

So, I found some responses on stackoverflow that say to update cacert.pem file.
I did it, added `CURLOPT_CAINFO => $cainfo,`
in `$options` and put `curl.cainfo = "PATH_TO/cacert.pem"` in both of my `php.ini` (apache + php  => WAMP). (`PATH_TO` already replaced by my true path).

Anyway, after all thoses changes, I still have the same issue.
I have to work under php 5.3, would it be the cause?

**EDIT 3**

Finnally found my answer. I should have look for curl options more carefully...

In command prompt `-k` allows an insecure connexion.

So, in php, I just have to set `CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER` to `false`.
FYI, I based myself on the doc that the distant web api gave to me .

Regards,

Comment: `die(curl_error($curl))`. boolean false just means an error occured, and curl_error() will tell you what the error was.

Comment: cf edit. (thank you)